# How to set Contextual filter of views for profile2 module?

Tags: 7, users, views

I want to show some data of users in their profile page. I'm using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) and [profile2](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2) modules.

In contextual filter I set `"user ID from url"` in `uid Contxtual filter`.

But this views don't show anything. When I set `"Display all results for the specified field"` this views block shows all users data in any profile page.
url of profile pages is `"www.example.com/profile-stores/uid".` actually in this project, I have 2 type of users. one of these is `"stores"`. for example I want to show `"address"` of stores in their profile page. I'm using Profile2 to create some types of user.

**Image-1**

> [image]

**Image-2**

> [image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can you please explain, What you want to add on user's profile. Because, most of the things you can add from the normal default  profile. Hence it can be understood that you need profile2 and further views or not. So, first we can figure out whether you actually need profile2+views or only profile or almost profile2 can do your job. Please edit your answer to add details.

Comment: I edited my Question. Is it complete?